# Delphi 10.3 : required package not found

Tags: delphi

I installed version Delphi 10.3CE and all the items I had on 10.2. Specifically, I refer to cyComponents 8.26 (i had version 8.12). An app sends me an error message `[dcc32 Fatal Error] E2202 Required package 'dpkCindyDBCtrlsPackD10' not found` although it is not mentioned at any point in the source code (program's and cindy's). It is likely to be a reference to an earlier one dcp, but I do not know how to identify it. Is there a way I can find that is mentioned?
The command line of the app is :

```
        Checking project dependencies...
Building myApp.dproj (Debug, Win32)
brcc32 command line for "myApp.vrc"
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\cgrc.exe -c65001 myApp.vrc -fomyApp.res 
brcc32 command line for "myAppResource.rc"
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\cgrc.exe -c65001 myAppResource.rc -fomyApp.dres 
dcc32 command line for "myApp.dpr"
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\dcc32.exe -$O- -$W+ -$J+ -$Q+ -$C- -     LUrtl;DbxCommonDriver;DataSnapClient;DbxClientDriver;

dpkCindyDBCtrlsPackD10; JvDlgs;vtable250;JvControls;JvStdCtrls;bdertl;dbrtl; IndyProtocols;vcldb;VclSmp;pkCindyCoreD10;JvDB;JvCustom;inet;myCompss10 
--no-config -B -Q -TX.exe - AGenerics.Collections=System.Generics.Collections;Generics.Defaults=System.Generics.Defaults;WinTypes=Winapi.Windows;
WinProcs=Winapi.Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE -DDEBUG;myApp -ES:\appDir\bin -I"c:\program files 
(x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\lib\Win32\debug";S:\appDir\JEDI\jcl\lib\d26\win32\debug;s:\appDir\general;s:\appDir\myComps\TFieldUpdate;
S:\appDir\DelphiTwain\units;S:\appDir\cyComponents8.26\Core;S:\appDir\cyComponents8.26\VCLPack;"S:\appDir\System Info (Magenta)";
S:\appDir\NativeExcel\Source;"C:\Program Files (x86)\ComponentAce\AbsoluteDatabase\Lib\Delphi 10.3 and C++ Builder 10.3 (Rio)";"C:\Program Files 
(x86)\ComponentAce\ZipForge\Lib\Delphi 10.3 and C++ Builder 10.3 (Rio)";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\Imports";
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Dcp;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include";"C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Devart\VirtualDAC for RAD Studio 10.3\Lib\Win32";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\VirtualDAC for RAD Studio 10.3\Bin\Win32";
S:\appDir\cyComponents8.26\Core;S:\appDir\cyComponents8.26\VCLPack;S:\appDir\JEDI\jcl\lib\d26\win32;S:\appDir\JEDI\jcl\source\include;
S:\appDir\JEDI\jvcl\lib\D26\win32;S:\appDir\JEDI\jvcl\common;S:\appDir\JEDI\jvcl\Resources;"c:\program files 
(x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\lib\Win32\release";S:\appDir\JEDI\jvcl\run;S:\appDir\myComps;S:\appDir\OtherComp 
-LEC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl - 
LNC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Dcp -NSWinapi; System.Win;Data.Win; Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;Vcl;Vcl.Imaging;Vcl.Touch;Vcl.Samples;Vcl.Shell; -Os:\appDir\general;
s:\appDir\myComps\TFieldUpdate;S:\appDir\DelphiTwain\units;S:\appDir\cyComponents8.26\Core;S:\appDir\cyComponents8.26\VCLPack;"S:\appDir\System 
....
....
-NBC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Dcp -NHC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\hpp\Win32  myApp.dpr   
[dcc32 Fatal Error] E2202 Required package 'dpkCindyDBCtrlsPackD10' not found
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:00.7
```

Comment: Package files are never listed in the source, especially design time packages. Try Project->Options.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
I open the file myApp.dproj with notepad and there was the reference. I deleted and now all work fine.